# android studio setcontentview vs oncreate

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I found myself in a weird spot and i don't know which approach I should take here.
I don't like the idea on creating activities and close the old ones to go forth in my app.

so here is my approach:
I am changing `contentView` to another layout(a second activity layout), but here the obvious catch, since no activity is created, the `oncreate()` method isn't called either and no functionality is initialized for that layout.
I wonder if there is a possibility to get the effect of the `oncreate()` method, without calling it, so i can let the initialization in the activity class and don't have to implement it in the first activity.
I am open to any tips.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome to [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please use formatting tools within post form to make your post more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically achieved with [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) or custom Views. With Fragments there is framework support for backstack management, and each Fragment has lifecycle callbacks, so I would recommend using those.

Comment: thanks for the tipp, ill definitely check that out, im totally new to android so i dont have the overview of all the complexity it brings.